# How to call a component inside a component using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm creating a simple web site using React, MobX state tree and react-router.

Basically, each page of the site (Page1, Page2 and Page3) has to contain a menu that is different for desktop and mobile devices.

This is my structure:

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react'
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import { State } from './states'
import { Routes } from './Routes'
import { history } from './states/index'

function renderApp() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider state={State}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
}
```

Routes.tsx is:

```
function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>
}


function RedirectToHomepage() {
  return <Redirect to="/" />
}

function withHeader(Component: React.ComponentClass) {
  return class withHeader extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="flex flex-column w-100 h-100">
          <Header />
          <Component />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

@inject('state')
@observer
class WithMenu extends React.Component<IStateable> {
  menuWidth = () => {
    const { ui } = this.props.state
    if (ui.isSmallDevice) {
      return ui.isMenuOpen ? 'w-100 h-100' : 'w0 h0'
    } else {
      return 'w-20 min-w5 max-w6 h-100'
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const { ui } = this.props.state
    const menuWidth = this.menuWidth()
    const showMenu = ui.isDesktop || ui.isMenuOpen

    return (
      <div className={`w-100 h-100 flex`}>
        {showMenu && <Menu className={`${menuWidth}`} />}
        {!showMenu && <div className={`flex-auto`}>{children}</div>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={withHeader(Homepage)} />
      <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
      <Route path={path} exact component={withHeader(Page1)} />
      <Route path={path} exact component={withHeader(Page2)} />
      <Route path={path} exact component={withHeader(Page3)} />
      <Route component={RedirectToHomepage} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

What I would like to have is Page1, Page2 and Page3 with Header and Menu.
So, it's possible to build a function that I can call like `component={withHeaderAndMenu(Page1)}`?
I don't want to repeat the logic in `WithMenu` class inside each component.

I try to put  here:

```
function renderApp() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <WithMenu>
      <Provider state={State}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Routes />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </WithMenu>
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
}
```

But then I have no router.

I need help. Thanks a lot

Comment: It's possible using this - https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: @ravibagul91 Thanks but can you add a working example with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
function withHeaderAndMenu(Component: React.ComponentClass) {
  return class WithHeaderAndMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="flex flex-column w-100 h-100">
          <Header />
          <WithMenu />
          <Component />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

And:

```
      <Route path={path} exact component={withHeaderAndMenu(Page1)} />
      <Route path={path} exact component={withHeaderAndMenu(Page2)} />
      <Route path={path} exact component={withHeaderAndMenu(Page3)} />
```